# Magento cart items check

Tags: magento, checkout, custom-attribute

How can I check if all the cart items have my custom attribute? And if item/items all have the custom attribute prints a message but if one of the cart item/items doesn't have the custom attribute, it prints an error message in the checkout?

Comment: What do you mean by custom attribute, in other words, how do you set it or how would the customer fix the problem? I think you should probably just try another product type if you want to have product options mandatory.

Comment: I have a product attribute called Fast Delivery and it is a yes/no attribute. I want to check in the checkout page if all the cart items have Fast Delivery attribute Yes and if it is display a message,if any of the cart items have the Fast Delivery attribute No then display an error message saying that 'One of the products in your cart can not be delivered today' @Christoffer Bubach

Comment: Ah, ok that clears it up. What I would do is to buy/get a module for dynamic shipping rules, so you can set conditions for if a shipping method is available or not.  See this for example - https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shipping-rules-by-amasty.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code

```
<?php
$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$error = "";
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $product = $productModel->load($item->getProduct()->getId());
    if($product->getData('your_attribute_code')){
        $message = "your message for items have attribute";
        $error = 0;
    }else{
        $message = "your message for items have no attributes";
        $error = 1;
        break;
    }
}
if($error == 1){
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($message);
}else{
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($message);   
}

?>
```